# How to randomly delete a number of lines from a big file?

Tags: python, bash, random, sed, awk

I have a big text file of 13 GB with 158,609,739 lines and I want to randomly select 155,000,000 lines.

I have tried to scramble the file and then cut the 155000000 first lines, but it's seem that my ram memory (16GB) isn't enough big to do this. The pipelines i have tried are:

```
shuf file | head -n 155000000
sort -R file | head -n 155000000
```

Now instead of selecting lines, I think is more memory efficient delete 3,609,739 random lines from the file to get a final file of 155000000 lines.

Comment: Are 155000000 is exactly necessary, can you accept +-one thousand?

Comment: Yes, I need exactly 150000000 lines, that's one of the biggest problems...

Comment: I can't imagine what causes you to need this specific number of lines...

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I need a dataset to do a simulation. I hope some day I'll write a paper of my work, so I strongly prefer to write "We use 155 million of reads as input dataset for the simulation" instead of "We use 154447842 reads of as input dataset for the simulation"...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you copy each line of the file to the output, assess its probability that it should be deleted. The first line should have a 3,609,739/158,609,739 chance of being deleted. If you generate a random number between 0 and 1 and that number is less than that ratio, don't copy it to the output. Now the odds for the second line are 3,609,738/158,609,738; if that line is not deleted, the odds for the third line are 3,609,738/158,609,737. Repeat until done.

Because the odds change with each line processed, this algorithm guarantees the exact line count. Once you've deleted 3,609,739 the odds go to zero; if at any time you would need to delete every remaining line in the file, the odds go to one.

Comment: ah yes, also known as [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)

Comment: @DarrenYin: No, this is not reservoir sampling.  In reservoir sampling, you don't know the total number of items beforehand.

Comment: I liked this algorithm, but isn't perfect because the first part of the file have bigger chance to get deleted... isn't it?

Comment: @Geparada, the odds of a line being deleted will fluctuate randomly but on average should remain constant. Consider that once you're halfway through the file, half of the total lines that should be deleted will already be gone and the odds will now be 1804869/79304869.

Comment: @Mark Ransom but... what if the odds never go to zero?? maybe I will have to read the file more than once... thanks anyways, your algorithm is nice!

Comment: @Geparada, if the odds don't go to zero they will be 1/1 for the last line, so that line will be deleted. Which reminds me of a couple of subtleties I left out of the answer: use a random number range that is up to *but not including* 1.0, and compare with `random < odds` (Not `<=`).

Comment: @Mark Ranson Thanks for your patience... finally I think I understood your whole idea... I made a python with your algorithm that works perfect

Answer (score 10):

You could always pre-generate which line numbers (a list of 3,609,739 random numbers selected without replacement) you plan on deleting, then just iterate through the file and copy to another, skipping lines as necessary. As long as you have space for a new file this would work.

You could select the random numbers with [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample)
E.g.,

```
random.sample(xrange(158609739), 3609739)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Proof of Mark Ransom's Answer

Let's use numbers easier to think about (at least for me!):

- 10 items
- delete 3 of them

First time through the loop we will assume that the first three items get deleted -- here's what the probabilities look like:

- first item:    3 / 10 = 30%
- second item:   2 /  9 = 22%
- third item:    1 /  8 = 12%
- fourth item:   0 /  7 = 0 %
- fifth item:    0 /  6 = 0 %
- sixth item:    0 /  5 = 0 %
- seventh item:  0 /  4 = 0 %
- eighth item:   0 /  3 = 0 %
- ninth item:    0 /  2 = 0 %
- tenth item:    0 /  1 = 0 %

As you can see, once it hits zero, it stays at zero.  But what if nothing is getting deleted?

- first item:    3 / 10 =  30%
- second item:   3 /  9 =  33%
- third item:    3 /  8 =  38%
- fourth item:   3 /  7 =  43%
- fifth item:    3 /  6 =  50%
- sixth item:    3 /  5 =  60%
- seventh item:  3 /  4 =  75%
- eighth item:   3 /  3 = 100%
- ninth item:    2 /  2 = 100%
- tenth item:    1 /  1 = 100%

So even though the probability varies per line, overall you get the results you are looking for.  I went a step further and coded a test in Python for one million iterations as a final proof to myself -- remove seven items from a list of 100:

```
# python 3.2
from __future__ import division
from stats import mean  # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stats
import random

counts = dict()
for i in range(100):
    counts[i] = 0

removed_failed = 0

for _ in range(1000000):
    to_remove = 7
    from_list = list(range(100))
    removed = 0
    while from_list:
        current = from_list.pop()
        probability = to_remove / (len(from_list) + 1)
        if random.random() < probability:
            removed += 1
            to_remove -= 1
            counts[current] += 1
    if removed != 7:
        removed_failed += 1

print(counts[0], counts[1], counts[2], '...',
      counts[49], counts[50], counts[51], '...',
      counts[97], counts[98], counts[99])
print("remove failed: ", removed_failed)
print("min: ", min(counts.values()))
print("max: ", max(counts.values()))
print("mean: ", mean(counts.values()))
```

and here's the results from one of the several times I ran it (they were all similar):

```
70125 69667 70081 ... 70038 70085 70121 ... 70047 70040 70170
remove failed:  0
min:  69332
max:  70599
mean:  70000.0
```

A final note:  Python's `random.random()` is [0.0, 1.0) (doesn't include 1.0 as a possibility).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for ["Algorithm S" from section 3.4.2 of Knuth (D. E. Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming. Volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms, second edition. Addison-Wesley, 1981)](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/random_sample.html).

You can see several implementations at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_algorithm_S

The [Perlmonks list has some Perl implementations of Algorithm S and Algorithm R](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=177092) that might also prove useful.

These algorithms rely on there being a meaningful interpretation of floating point numbers like 3609739/158609739, 3609738/158609738, etc. which *might* not have sufficient resolution with a standard `Float` datatype, unless the `Float` datatype is implemented using numbers of [double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision) or larger.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution using Python:

```
import random

skipping = random.sample(range(158609739), 3609739)

input = open(input)
output = open(output, 'w')

for i, line in enumerate(input):
    if i in skipping:
        continue
    output.write(line)

input.close()
output.close()
```

Here's another using Mark's method:

```
import random

lines_in_file = 158609739
lines_left_in_file = lines_in_file
lines_to_delete = lines_in_file - 155000000

input = open(input)
output = open(output, 'w')

try:
    for line in input:
        current_probability = lines_to_delete / lines_left_in_file
        lines_left_in_file -= 1
        if random.random < current_probability:
            lines_to_delete -= 1
            continue
        output.write(line)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("More than %d lines in the file" % lines_in_file)
finally:
    input.close()
    output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code before seeing that Darren Yin has expressed its principle.

I've modified my code to take the use of name `skipping` (I didn't dare to choose `kangaroo` ...) and of keyword `continue` from Ethan Furman whose code's principle is the same too.

I defined default arguments for the parameters of the function in order that the function can be used several times without having to make re-assignement at each call.

```
import random
import os.path

def spurt(ff,skipping):
    for i,line in enumerate(ff):
        if i in skipping:
            print 'line %d excluded : %r' % (i,line)
            continue
        yield line

def randomly_reduce_file(filepath,nk = None,
                         d = {0:'st',1:'nd',2:'rd',3:'th'},spurt = spurt,
                         sample = random.sample,splitext = os.path.splitext):

    # count of the lines of the original file
    with open(filepath) as f:  nl = sum(1 for _ in f)

    # asking for the number of lines to keep, if not given as argument
    if nk is None:
        nk = int(raw_input('  The file has %d lines.'
                           '  How many of them do you '
                           'want to randomly keep ? : ' % nl))

    # transfer of the lines to keep,
    # from one file to another file with different name
    if nk<nl:
        with open(filepath,'rb') as f,\
             open('COPY'.join(splitext(filepath)),'wb') as g:
            g.writelines(  spurt(f,sample(xrange(0,nl),nl-nk) )  )
            # sample(xrange(0,nl),nl-nk) is the list
            # of the counting numbers of the lines to be excluded 
    else:
        print '   %d is %s than the number of lines (%d) in the file\n'\
              '   no operation has been performed'\
              % (nk,'the same' if nk==nl else 'greater',nl)
```

Answer (score -1):

With the [$RANDOM](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html) variable you can get a random number between 0 and 32,767.

With this, you could read in each line, and see if $RANDOM is less than `155,000,000 / 158,609,739 * 32,767` (which is 32,021), and if so, let the line through.

Of course, this wouldn't give you *exactly* 150,000,000 lines, but pretty close to it depending on the normality of the random number generator.

**EDIT:** Here is some code to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
  if (( $RANDOM < 32021 ))
  then
    echo $line
  fi
done
```

Call it like so:

```
thatScript.sh <inFile.txt >outFile.txt
```

Comment: Mark's answer shows how to modify this to make it exactly 150M lines.